# PHP TCPDF Export for Standard Address Labels

Tags: php, tcpdf

Standard label which are printed on a special sheet of paper fit on 3 columns with 10 rows on each sheet.  However the blocks have to be set in a specific size in order for the labels to display correctly on the sheet once you peel off the address.

i have setup my HTML which i print with TCPDF writeHTML function. However, i'm trying to get the height as exact as possible but TCPDF does not seems to support height measurement.  Is there a standard template that i could use that would output the correct html for TCPDF to print it correctly on an address label sheet?

Thanks.

Comment: You get this right? I've been banging my head against it for a week, tcpdf has gotten me the closest.. but its still not quite right.

Comment: I ended up using a php library called fpdf17 which did what i was looking for to print address labels.

Comment: May resolved: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29712374/how-can-i-use-tcpdf-to-make-2x6-sheets-of-labels-that-include-2d-barcodes-withou/61862155#61862155](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29712374/how-can-i-use-tcpdf-to-make-2x6-sheets-of-labels-that-include-2d-barcodes-withou/61862155#61862155)